# Where is this hadith attested "He who knows himself knows his Lord"?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I've read that the following:

> He who knows himself knows his Lord

is a hadith. Where is it attested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The saying you are referring to:

> من عرف نفسه فقد عرف ربه
>
> He who knows himself knows his Lord

This is not a hadith attributed to the Prophet ﷺ, but it is a saying attributed to [Yahya ibn Mu'ādh ar-Rāzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahya_ibn_Mu%27adh_al-Razi) as:

- [Shams ad-Dīn as-Sakhāwi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Sakhawi) mentioned in his book [*Al-Maqāsid al-Hassana*, Vol. 2, pp. 657](https://al-maktaba.org/book/23177/634) as attested by  Al-Hāfidh Abu Sa'd as-Sam'āni
- [Ibn Hajar al-Haytami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-Haytami) in his book [*Al-Fatāwa al-Hadīthiyya*, pp.206](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1922/205).

There are numerous other scholars that said this hadith is a fabricated one (e.g., [Ibn Taymiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Taymiyyah), Ismā'īl al-'Ajalōni, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

In some references, it is referred to as a saying of The Prophet (pbuh) and in some others it is considered as a hadith from Imam Ali (A.S.). But in both cases consequence of the people who narrate this hadith is not mentioned (This hadith is a *Morsal* ‍‍`مُرسَل`), although the concept of this statement is true.

Comment: What do you mean by *Morsal*?

Comment: @MoziburUllah — Hadith Mursal means there is a discontinuity in the narration chain (see [Can you explain the status of mursal hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35630/8393)).